# django not saving media files in production

Tags: django, deployment, apache2, media

I set up django project on ubuntu 18.04 and apache2 but there is a problem.
Media files don't save.
When I try to upload file using django-filer I get 500 internal server error(I wrote simple plugin with charfield and filefield - the same happens) independently from DEBUG=True/False setting.
I uploaded few files using manage.py runserver and this works great - I can even use these files in production but an attempt to upload any new one cause error
settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/mysite/public/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/mysite/public/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')]
```

apache configuration:

```
alias /static /mysite/public/static
<Directory /mysite/public/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

alias /media /mysite/public/media
<Directory /mysite/public/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /mysite/src/proj>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-home=/mysite/venv python-path=/mysite/src/
WSGIProcessGroup mysite
WSGIScriptAlias / /mysite/src/proj/wsgi.py
```

In conclusion:
manage.py runserver works great.
On production server I can manage files which were uploaded earlier but an attempt to upload a new one cause error 500.

Comment: If you used `DEBUG=True` in production can't you get the error from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change permissions of the `media` folder. Something like

```
sudo chmod -R 775 your_django_project/public/media
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've browsed whole web and found nothing